# How read and search in xml with asp classic

Tags: xml, asp-classic

this is my xml format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <CO IID="23" NC="10100594100" CFA="Memco"  />
</Root>
```

how can i find key like NC o CFA and value from this file with asp Classic ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath. This should get you started. It will retrieve the value of the `NC` attribute.

```
Set doc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")   
doc.Async = False
doc.Load "c:\path\to\your.xml"

Set a = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/CO/@NC") 

If Not a Is Nothing Then    
    Response.Write a.Text
End If
```